# Prerequisites for Cocchiarella modal logic book?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, modal-logic

I’m hoping at some point to begin working through Cocchiarella and Freund’s book *Modal Logic: Its Syntax and Semantics*. Have any of you used this book before? What would you say are its prerequisites, if any? I’ve heard that it’s [overly technical](https://www.logicmatters.net/2009/10/14/modal-logic-with-a-lot-more-tears-than-necessary/) and tends not to sufficiently explain or justify its idiosyncrasies in emphasis, symbolism, or formulation. I confess I find its symbolic approach appealing, though, given my ignorance of logic, this preference is certainly aesthetic rather than prudential or philosophical. In any case, I’d love to hear whether you all agree with this criticism.

As regards prerequisites, I know the authors make use of NBG set theory (and to this end, I imagine Fitting & Smullyan’s *Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis* might be helpful). Are there others?